# In Google Spreadsheets, how do you iterate over a cell range and use the index counter?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table in which I have a list of amounts, each belonging to one of 15 categories

```
    A         B
1    cat  |  amount
    _____|________
2    1    |   12
3    1    |    4
4    4    |   18,90
5    15   |   19,79
6    4    |   23
7    4    |   12
8    15   |   19
9    9    |    1,90
10   8    |   18
```

I want to list each category with the sum of all amounts belonging to this category.
For each category, for example `1`  I could do `=SUM(IF(A2=1;B2;0) + IF(A3=1;B3;0) + IF(A4=1;B4;0))`
I was hoping to find something like =FOR((A2:A10);SUM(IF(Ai=1;Bi;0))) that iterates over all rows A2 to A10 and sums up all amounts where category is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's best done via the `QUERY` formula.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(DATA!B:C, "SELECT B, SUM(C) WHERE B IS NOT NULL GROUP BY B")
```

If you want to sort by amount, then use the following formula:

```
=QUERY(DATA!B:C, "SELECT B, SUM(C) WHERE B IS NOT NULL GROUP BY B ORDER BY SUM(C) LABEL SUM(C) 'Total Amount'")
```

I've added this formula to the example file.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: [sum by query](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdEItLTF3cnNoa2g4QmtrRlpWcWZnRXc&usp=sharing)

Comment: Well thank you! One Question though: For the first argument `DATA!B:C`  I would like to select data from two columns that are not next to each other like in my sample. How would I do that?

Comment: Ok I found out I have to adjust the SUM(C) accordingly!

Comment: How Do I sort by Amount? `GROUP BY B SORT BY E` for example (does not work)?

Comment: @tzippy See revised answer. Good luck (Servus).

Answer (score -1):

`=sumif(A2:A,1,B2:B)`

see:

http://anandexcels.wordpress.com/tag/google-docs-sumif-function/

there are also database functions, e.g. `dsum()` 
and SQL style `QUERY()` functions